# mysql: how to get data from 3 newest months in database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I was stuck about use command in mysql to query rows in 3 newest months. This is example:

this is db :

```
row 1 : 2012/02/10 - id : 1
row 2 : 2012/03/15 - id : 2
row 3 : 2012/05/04 - id : 3
row 4 : 2012/06/04 - id : 4
```

today is : `2013/03/28`

How can i write a command to get data rows from 3 months newest in database :
The true result will be : row 2 3 4

Update -----

```
Table name = sa_cms_post | col date : createdAt datetime - 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

Comment: what's your table structure? Is the date an actual date field or string?

Comment: @Cfreak : i was updated my question about the table information. :)

Comment: why is record `2` still on the list? do you based it on months?

Comment: i need get 3 newest months, not 3 last months. so in example i take curent time is 2013 , but if true, we need have data from months 06 05 03 because this is 3 newest months in database.

Comment: Is there any records for the same month?

Comment: @jim yes. any data in 3 newest months

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give this a try,

```
SELECT  *
FROM    sa_cms_post
WHERE   MONTH(createdAt) BETWEEN
                         MONTH(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
```

Comment: Tested ! and DONE !. Thankyou so much my friend :)

Comment: This solution is **incorrect**. It will fail on this data: [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0bf2/2)

Comment: he wants 3 newest, as in trailing months

Comment: @mvp but the current month is still needed.

Comment: @mvp the solution was based on the given data and the desired result.

Comment: no - you do not need current date to get 3 trailing months from some data set

Comment: @mvp if the op didn't exactly worded the question correctly, then perhaps the example data and the desired will speak for it. anyway, if my answer is wrong. the user can certainly uncheck and i will delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, by *newest 3 months* you actually mean to get *3 trailing months* rows from the table, and current date does not really matter to you. In that case, this works ([SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74df3/4)):

```
SELECT *
FROM sa_cms_post
WHERE createdAt > date_sub(
    (SELECT max(createdAt) FROM sa_cms_post),
    INTERVAL 3 month
)
```

Comment: because it gets 3 trailing months from given data set (without regard to current date)

Comment: @downvoter: this answer is valid for trailing 3 months from dataset. if you think I did not understand question correctly, say so.